# Some examples for usage of 'anecdotiquement'

Tags: usage, adverbes

I have a hard time to find some useful usages for the word 'anecdotiquement' in some examples. 
Could you please give me some example that contains this adverb?

Thank you

Comment: You might find it difficult to find lots of examples because I think we would rather use *de façon anecdotique* than the adverb *anecdotiquement*.

Comment: @Laure: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I don't know exactly what 'anecdote' means? searching in dictionaries and some examples I can't understand what it means exactly!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The adverb *anecdotiquement* comes from the meaning of the adjective *anecdotique* which applies to something that does not generalize, and only tells minor facts that are more or less picturesque. <sup>1</sup>

This is what @aCOSwt says (differently from me) in [their answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/39536/358). So I'll give you different examples from theirs, with their  translations into English.

> Il se trouve enfin en vallée de la Loire, plus anecdotiquement sur les terroirs chauds de l’Anjou et de la Touraine. ([Cépages de France](http://www.vindefrance-cepages.org/fr/encyclopedie-des-cepages-de-france))

(It can be found in the Loire Valley and, on a smaller scale/more rarely on the warm soils of Anjou and Touraine).

> On le voit plus anecdotiquement sur les photos des visiteurs, et pourtant ce petit bijou plaît souvent. ([Facebook page of the town of Auch](https://www.facebook.com/TourismeAuch/photos/a.188286174670516/1300054556827000/?type=1&theater))

(It is rarely seen on the visitors' photos although this little jewel is much appreciated.)

I'd like to add that it is more common in everyday usage to say *de façon anecdotique* rather than *anecdotiquement*.

> Quelques gouttes seront possibles très localement, mais de façon anecdotique ([weather site](https://www.meteolanguedoc.com/actualites-meteo-languedoc/retour-de-l-ete-en-plein-automne-jusqu-a-33-c-sur-le-languedoc/p1122))

(We might get a few rare drops is some areas)

---

> <sup>1</sup>
>    Qui ne généralise pas, se contente d'exposer des faits mineurs et plus ou moins pittoresques. (*Dictionnaire culturel en langue française*)

Answer (score 8):

Si anecdotiquement ne se présente que très rarement en tant que vedette dans les dictionnaires, il n'en reste pas moins utilisé par des *bons* auteurs :

*Je veux traiter anecdotiquement la révolution de 1830* (Talleyrand)

On peut le trouver aussi dans la littérature moderne, très souvent lorsque l'auteur souhaite présenter la dimension symbolique d'un évènement, d'un personnage, sans oublier quelque fait de détail annexe : Il dira alors :

*Symboliquement... blahblah et anecdotiquement... blahblah*

*Symboliquement comme anecdotiquement, il n'en reste pas moins un héros* (Brémond)

Les comparatifs : Lorsque l'auteur se livre dans une suite de détails anecdotiques et souhaite en livrer un qui l'est **plus** ou **moins**

*Moins anecdotiquement, R. Ledrut considère des questions que la philosophie se pose...*

On retrouve enfin quasi systématiquement cet adverbe dans des comptes-rendus d'expériences / opérations médicales dans lesquels l'auteur cherche à dégager des principes généraux et va noter ainsi *anecdotiquement* quelques faits qui lui semblent important de mentionner bien que, à priori, relevant d'un cas particulier dans le cadre d'une gradation d'adverbes :

*Le traitement anticoagulant préventif... Lorsqu'il est prescrit, il concerne **surtout** les héparines, **rarement** les non fractionnées, **anecdotiquement** les AVK.* (Boissier-Mollard-Carpentier)

Comment: Vu que tu as répondu en français je pense que le PO n'a pas lu ta question, ce qui est regrettable. Je me suis permis de répondre parce que c'est toi qui a raison. Fais moi signe si tu as besoin que tes exemples soient traduits. Il est quand même important dans l'intérêt du site que les meilleures réponses soient « élues ». Je t'ai cité dans ma réponse et ta cote remonte.

Comment: @Laure : Merci pour ta sympathie et pour toute la peine que tu te donnes ici souvent. J'y suis infiniment plus sensible que je ne peux l'être à ces histoires de *réputation* et en particulier d'élection en tant que meilleure réponse que je tiens pour une absurdité sans nom.

Comment: Quand je dis  « Il est quand même important dans l'intérêt du site que les meilleures réponses soient « élues », je ne parle pas de ta réputation mais de ce que ceux qui n'ont pas les connaissances pour juger retiennent ! » Rien de personnel. Mais je vois à cette heure que les francophones qui connaissent la langue française ont réagi par leurs votes ↑.

Answer (score 2):

Voici quelques exemples de parution :

https://fr.glosbe.com/fr/fr/anecdotiquement

http://www.agropolis.fr/pdf/dossier-lutte-biologique.pdf (page 33 du document)

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22anecdotiquement%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_f

https://www.senscritique.com/film/Black_Panther/critique/40835530

L'adverbe existe mais je crois qu'un locuteur natif dirait plutôt *de manière/de façon anecdotique*.

Answer (score -4):

You find in French the adjective corresponding to the noun "anecdote", that is, "anecdotique" but you do no find "anecdotiquement" in the Academie's dictionary nor in the TLFi, although in the past décades it has been used in print ; French is a language, unlike English, in which there exists a certain squeamishness for providing the adverb corresponding to an adjective when this adverb is very restricted in use and in other circumstances having to do amongst other criteria with a felt lack of specificity in the adverb; in a case such as the present one the French had rather say "de façon anecdotique", "au moyen d'anecdotes", "par des anecdotes", etc.

- Cette explication est faite au moyen d'une anecdote.
  *This explanation was made anecdotically.*
- Cet écrivain est surtout connu du fait d'anecdotes le concernant.
  *This writer is known mostly anecdotically.*
- Cela a été illustré par des anecdotes.
  *This has been illustrated anecdotically.*

Comment: @Freshman42 *anecdotiquement* does not come from *anecdote* but from *anecdotique* which has acquired a different meaning.

Comment: I am baffled one can seriously state that *anedoctiquement* cannot be found in French. We can argue whether it is common or not, recent or not... but *not found* ??? It only takes a Google search to find 1000s of occurences, including entries in dictionaries. Here is an ngram that shows it is "alive and kicking": https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=anecdotiquement&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Canecdotiquement%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98869/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-some-examples-for-usage-of-anecdotiquement).